# Both If and Else are executing. What is wrong here?

Tags: java

I’m just really learning Java, going through tutorials through online and books, so please forgive any basic mistakes I’m making. I am not understanding why both if and else is executing.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Primes {

    static boolean prime(long num) {
        boolean isPrime = false;
        for (int i = 2; i <= num - 1; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
            } else {
                isPrime = true;
            }
        }
        return isPrime;
    }

    static void generate(long max) {
        long num = 2;
        for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++) {
            if (prime(num)) {
                System.out.println(num);
            }
            num++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Maximum number of primes?");
        int max = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        generate(max);
    }

}
```

If I change the code little bit. It is working accordingly. I changed code like this.

```
static boolean prime(long num) {
    boolean isPrime = true;
    for (int i = 2; i <= num - 1; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
        }
    }
    return isPrime;
}
```

But I want to know to why the first condition is not working.

```
if (condition) {
  // block of code to be executed if the condition is true
} else {
  // block of code to be executed if the condition is false
}
```

How the condition can be both true and false in my code. Anybody please help me on this.

Comment: You are not returning the true / false when it occurs, instead, you're "overwriting" the value over and over again until the loop reaches its end, only _then_ the value is returned.

Comment: Because you don't terminate the loop when you determine that the number is not prime (You would do this with a break).  The latter version is correct because you are assuming the number is prime, and setting the flag to false, it is not prime, only if you determine that it is not.  You can also use `break` to terminate the loop as soon as you determine it's not prime.  You can also replace the flag with a `return false` and `return true` in the if and in the end respectively.

Comment: @asm It would produce an invalid result if `return true` was added, e.g. 9 is not a prime number but your solution would say it is as it cannot be divided by 2 and thus the else would terminate the method with true.

Comment: Also, the whole "prime" logic is flawed as 2 is a prime number yet it would say it isn't...

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy .. Thank you.. I can get that am not returning when true/false occurs. return will give back the current value of the variable in this case.  But consider if 4 is the value of N. It should only go inside if condition right. in my case it is going inside if and else. It wont satisfy the else condition right?

Answer (score 2):

Get a look at your code:

```
boolean isPrime = false;
for (int i = 2; i <= num - 1; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
        } else {
            isPrime = true;
        }
}
return isPrime;
```

Assume num = 10. So, loop iterating over these steps:
i = 2, i = 3, i = 4, i = 5, i = 6, i = 7, i = 8, i = 9

Each step processes inner logic:

```
        if (num % i == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
        } else {
            isPrime = true;
        }
```

And, for last step, where i = 9, isPrime = true.

And after that, when loop steps are over, `return isPrime;` is performed.

So, result of the last step will be returned. And as you should see, previous steps are meaningless.